# PowerApps: Filtering of related Dataverse table in a nested gallery - why?

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I am making a simple "Menu" app.
I have one DataVerse Table with Menu items (available meals) and another DataVerse Table with Menu item bookings (by people).
I set relation many-to-many.
Created a vertical gallery in Canvas App, set datasource to Table#1.
Created a nested vertical gallery and set datasource to ThisItem.Table#2.

All is fine - works!!!

Now, based on user's business role (like an Admin or a Standard user) I want to show either all bookings in the nested gallery or to show only user's bookings - and this is where I have a problem.

If I define datasource of nested gallery to something like that (see below), then it does not work, but does not work in a strange way, it looks like it sees the records but text labels do not show any data.

If(
varIsAdmin,
ThisItem.'Lunch Menu Bookings',
Filter(
ThisItem.'Lunch Menu Bookings',
StartsWith(
varUserName,
ThisRecord.'Owner (User)'.'Full Name'
)
)
)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70XYc.png)

If I change the formula to the version below, - it works OK.
Why??? I do not see any difference.
Can you explain, please?

Filter(
ThisItem.'Lunch Menu Bookings',
If(
varIsAdmin
true,
StartsWith(
varUserName,
ThisRecord.'Owner (User)'.'Full Name'
)
)
)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wKdT.png)